# PHP - Need a Templating system that can read from a data-source

Tags: php, forms, templates, report

for a project of mine - at the end of a process a form is generated. In my old system it was combination of Regex + HTML (which I've learnt is not very nice to maintain :))

So I've gone and done some research, but I can not seem to find the template engine I am after. I've been eyeing off **Twig & Smarty**, but I want the engine to be able to iterate through the custom tags, which in turn calls a **function** to **retrieve** the data which is read from a source **(basically a callback function)**. Since there is already a massive collection of data, and it can come in all different formats depending on how the user wants to display it.

I've also wanted to include **if** and **else** conditions

I hope I'm clear enough.

I'll provide a very basic example of the code from my template system

```
<html> 
  <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               Building
            </td>
            <td>
               <mi:seperated  seperator=", " source="building" key="type" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                Construction
            </td>
            <td>
              <mi:seperated  seperator=", " source="house" key="construction" default="N/A" />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                Floor
            </td>
            <td>
              <mi:value source="house" key="floor" default="N/A" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the end result would look like this.

```
<html> 
  <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               Building
            </td>
            <td>
               Double Storey, Domestic dwelling
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                Construction
            </td>
            <td>
              6 Bedrooms, Brick Veneer
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                Floor
            </td>
            <td>
               N/A
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

These form templates can be edited by anyone. So, I don't want to do down the path of 'PHP is a templating language', unless of course theres an easy way to restrict what code is executed.

edit: also just a quick note. the **callback** function is to handle the HTML output (since some tags can create complex output)

Comment: Any reason not to do this with plain old PHP, which is itself a templating engine? It even includes the alternate flow control syntax like `<?php if ($condition): ?> <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: @Michael Because everyone has access to the template. Normal users. I said so in my OP :( Major hacking potential

Comment: @Michael your comment gave me some thought and I've come up with a few ideas. I've written a very simple system which uses DOMDocument and goes through the nodes looking for all my custom namespace tags and converts them to appropriate PHP code :) and the if conditions only accept functions declared in the datasource class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Smarty you could create a plugin to handle your custom tags. A little something on plugins for Smarty http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins

I guess you would have to look at something like the [block functions](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.block.functions.tpl)

Comment: yeah I've been looking at smarty. If I can't get it to work the way I want, I may just draw inspiration from it and make a minimal template system. Had afew ideas throughout the course of the day